# /sbin/init exists but couldn’t execute it (error -13)

Tags: init, u-boot

I'm recompiling my project (https://github.com/warpme/minimyth2) to rpi3 (aarch64). 
I have all components compiled and now I'm trying to boot it on rpi3.

I'm using u-boot script from arm archlinux with replaced kernel image (Image.gz) and rootfs from my compilation

kernel boots.
Also I see also on console, kernel mounts OK 2nd partition (my rootfs content is here).

but later kernel log says:

```
Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn’t execute it (error -13)
Starting init: /sbin/sh exists but couldn’t execute it (error -13)
```

Accordingly to https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h?h=v4.16.14 "error -13" means `EACCES 13 /* Permission denied */.`

I double checked: both files are root:root and 755 (their dependencies as well). What else can cause EACCES here?

u-boot script is following:

```
# Set root partition to the second partition of boot device
part uuid ${devtype} ${devnum}:2 uuid

setenv bootargs console=ttyS1,115200 console=tty0 root=PARTUUID=${uuid} rw rootwait debug loglevel=7 smsc95xx.macaddr="${usbethaddr}"

if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} /Image; then
  if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} /dtbs/${fdtfile}; then
    if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${ramdisk_addr_r} /initramfs-linux.img; then
      booti ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r}:${filesize} ${fdt_addr_r};
    else
      booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r};
    fi;
  fi;
fi
```

so I think rootfs is mounted as rw

If anybody wants to look on my files, here are boot and rootfs partitions content:

hxxp://warped.inet2.org/boot.tar.bz2
hxxp://warped.inet2.org/root.tar.bz2

So summarising:

1\at rootfs mounting phase kernel says

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

2\ kernel is able to find init (and fallback to sh due failed init execution) as kernel says

`Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -13)
Starting init: /sbin/sh exists but couldn’t execute it (error -13)`

3\adding `"rootflags=exec"` to kernel command line cause mount of root fails.

For me it seems my kernel config is somehow broken as it is able to mount but can't execute on it.

Attaching my kernel cfg http://warped.inet2.org/kernel-config.tar.bz2) (pls look at linux-4.16.13-arm64-armv8.config)

Can somebody can look on it and verify is such config enough to mount rootfs without any initrd? (to confirm: I want mount SD card ext4 rootfs straight from kernel image).

Alternatively: can somebody provide me minimal aarch64 kernel config enough to U-boot rpi3 with generic 4.16 kernel with rootfs on SD ext4 partition and without any initrd?

(PS: My kernel config is based on archlinux aarch64 multiplatform kernel and is 99.9% equal to archlinux arm)

(below is screenshot form kernel log)
[boot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf9BO.jpg)

Comment: You could get the error by mounting root with noexec. Or /sbin/init could be a symbolic link to a non-existent file.

Comment: oh well - I double check: on 2nd partition of SD card I have /sbin/init and init has 755 - so I think issue isn't related to existence of init file. However noexec hypothesis is interesting. Kernel reports mounting rootfs partition as "mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)" So maybe no opts on mounting causes that rootfs is mounted with noexec? How can i change this?

Comment: I started to play with root mount options in kernel command line. Adding "rootflags=defaults" or "rootflags=exec" cause root partition isn't mounting successfully (kernel says "VFS unable mount root on device(179,2)". Probably because wrong kernel cmdline params. How can I ask kernel to mount with 'exec' rights?

Comment: exec is default when mounting.

Comment: Right regarding exec. Summarising: 1\at mounting phase kernel says "EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null); 2\ kernel is able to find init (and fallback to sh due failed init execution) as kernel says "Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -13)"; 3\adding ""rootflags=exec"" to kernel command line cause mount of root fails. For me it seems my kernel config is somehow broken as it is able to mount but can't execute on it. Attaching my kernel cfg - can somebody can look? (it is practically archlinux  aarch64 multiplatg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue was in glibc. 
I build with 2.17 and despite it is marketed as "first glibc supporting aarch64" - it not works for me. 
Upgrading glibc to 2.27 solves issue :-)

Thx everybody why tried help me with this!